# Why is Toast messages being overwritten and not shown in Nougat when called via Runnable?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-toast

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    ArrayList<String> toastMQ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        toastMQ = new ArrayList<String>();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toastMQ.add("Message1");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        callToast1();
        PreSleepToast pst = new PreSleepToast();
        pst.execute();
    }
    private Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for( int i = 0; i < toastMQ.size(); i++ ){
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastMQ.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
            }
        }
     };

    public class PreSleepToast extends AsyncTask<Void, byte[], Void> {
        /**
         * The sender socket on which we send connections.
         */
        public PreSleepToast() {
        }

        /**
         * Polling loop for outgoing connections.
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            handler.post(r);
            return null;
        };
    };

    public void callToast1(){
        toastMQ.add("Message2");
    }
}
```

Above is my source codes... I just want to try to collect a bunch of messages where I would be calling Thread.sleep(xxx) in between them before posting them out via Toast messages....somehow when I loop through them and post, in Nougat Androidv7.0 and above it only shows the last message...anyone has any idea why it behaves this way?

in Marshmallow it works fine, it displays first Message1 followed by Message2...in Nougat it only display "Message2" only...